# How to create individual node sets using abaqus python scripting?

Tags: python, abaqus

I am new to Python scripting in Abaqus. I am aware how to use the GUI but not really familiar with the scripting interface. However, I would like to know one specific thing. I would like to know how to assign a set to each individual node on a geometry's edges. I have thought about referencing the node numbers assigned to the geometry edges but don't know how I will do it.

The reason for creating a set for each node is that I would like to apply Periodic Boundary Conditions (PBC). Currently my model is a 2D Repeating Unit Cell (RUC) and I would like to apply a constraint equation between the opposite nodes on the opposite edges. To do that, I need to create a set for each node and then apply an equation on the corresponding set of nodes.

Just to add that the reason why I would like to use the Python scripting interface is because through the GUI, I can only make sets of nodes and create constraint equations for a simple mesh. But for a refined mesh, there will be a lot more constraint equations and a whole lot more sets.

Any suggestion of any kind would be really helpful.

Comment: Is this kind of information not found in the documentation?

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the way would be with the help of `getByBoundingBox(...)` method available for selecting nodes inside of a particular bounding box.

> allNodes = mdb.models[name].parts[name].nodes
>   allNodes.getByBoundingBox(xMin, yMin, zMin, xMax, yMax, zMax)
>   mdb.models[name].parts[name].Set(name=<name_i>, region=<regionObject_corresponding_to_node_i>)

One could always look for pointers in the replay file `*.rpy` of the current current session, which is mostly machine generated python code of the manual steps done in CAE.

*Abaqus > Scripting Reference > Python commands > Mesh commands > MeshNodeArray object* and *Abaqus > Scripting Reference > Python commands > Region commands > Set object* contains the relevant information.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Following is the code:
allNodes = mdb.models['Model-1'].parts['RUC'].nodes
allNodes.getByBoundingBox(-12.5, -7, 0, 12.5, 7, 0) 
mdb.models['Model-1'].parts['RUC'].sets['L0'].nodes(-12.5,-7.0,0.0).

However when I run the code, I get the error: ''KeyError: Unknown key L0''

How can I solve this error? I am starting from the bottom left edge and want to make a set of each node of the left edge from L0 to L26. Then I will move on to the right edge etc.

Comment: @Mohamad Hasan Hi, let's take a look what your code does: ```allNodes = mdb.models['Model-1'].parts['RUC'].nodes``` assigns all nodes in part 'RUC' to the variable ```allNodes```. Second, ```allNodes.getByBoundingBox(-12.5, -7, 0, 12.5, 7, 0)``` returns an array of node objects that lie within the specified bounding box, which is not assigned to any varible and is "lost" when you run next line of code. Third, ```mdb.models['Model-1'].parts['RUC'].sets['L0'].nodes(-12.5,-7.0,0.0)``` is calling an existing set 'L0', which looking at your first two lines of code, has not yet been created.